# bulk insert queries in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to insert thousands of records into my database, and because of these insert queries the page takes too long to reload.

How can I make my page load faster and run all insert queries at the same time?

Comment: its a one time thing? i mean thousands of insert for a single page load?

Comment: @Rogier, yes its one time thing, I think it requires fork or thread kind of thing for this parallel processing, is there a way to do this in rails3?

Comment: why don't write a .rb file and run it from the console? (rails c). And a other way is (depening on the data), to insert it direct in the DB.

Comment: I need to save all the facebook friends in my databse when one logs into the application with facebook login, and it takes too much time when one has so many friends in his facebook account, so I need to insert this FB friends data in background and let user to access the application. how can I do this? please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a gem that allow you to bulk insert : https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

Otherwise, maybe you could do the inserts in a background job.